# Localizing Core Data Properties

Tags: cocoa, core-data

I'm trying to localize my Core Data model in order to display better error messages. I followed the instructions on http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdUsingMOM.html without success.

My model file is v8.xcdatamodel, so my strings file is v8Model.string. I want to have the property "name" displayed as "Name". So I added the line

```
"Property/name" = "Name";
```

to the strings file. But it just does nothing when an error message is displayed. Any ideas what I missed?

thanks,
Martin

Comment: You show localization for a "Property" but then mention an "error message". How are you constructing your error message? Also, have you tried the "ErrorString" key?

Comment: I do nothing custom to construct the message. The first paragraph in http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSPersistentDocumentTutorial/06_CustomisingErrors/errors.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002834-SW1 states:

"If there was a validation error, the name of the property that failed validation is given as defined in the model (for example, “firstName”) rather than something more natural (such as “First name”) ... In order to give the user more information and help them to fix the problems, you can customize the display of property names and multiple errors."

Answer (score 0):

Your strings file should be `v8Model.strings`, but maybe that's just a typo in your question. Notice also that `.strings` files *must* be saved in UTF-16 encoding, as [documented here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSPersistentDocumentTutorial/06_CustomisingErrors/errors.html).

The `.strings` file should be saved in the appropriate localization folder, such as en.lproj.

Comment: I checked the encoding and the file name. Everything is correct.